# Visual Studio won't let me add project configurations

Tags: visual-studio-2015

According to the MSDN pages, I should be able to select Build > Configuration Manager, then select a project, and from the Configuration dropdown for that project click "New". But ... there is no such option. The only option is "Debug".

I can go to the top of the window, Active solution Configuration, and click "New" there. There's a box labeled "create new project configurations". But it's grayed out so I can't check it.

Is there some setting to allow me to create new project configurations? Some attribute of a project that makes this illegal?

I am running VS 2015 on Win 10.

Comment: Hi... I have the same issue. Can you share your trick (If this already solved)?

Answer (score 0):

Try, Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General -> Click "Show advanced build configurations" check box.  Hope it's what you need.

Comment: Hmm, thanks, but that's already checked. Checked or unchecked the configuration manager window looks the same.